# Extraer información de una consulta que esta en un for() PHP

Tags: php, array

Hola necesito su ayuda para poder extraer todos los datos de cualquiera de estos for(). EL problema que tengo es que sólo me retorna un valor en cualquiera de los casos, si me imprime bien la cadena, pero sólo si esta dentro del for(). ¿Alguna idea? :c

```
$objetos= new DB();
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) total_repetidos, Ciudadderesidencia FROM `Solicitudes` WHERE Id_usuarios = 1 && Procesamiento = 1 GROUP By Ciudadderesidencia HAVING total_repetidos > 1 ORDER BY total_repetidos DESC";
$resultado = $objetos->consultaregistros($query);    
echo $resultado; //array
echo "<br>";
for($x=0;$x<count($resultado);$x++){          
  $ciudad = $resultado[$x]['Ciudadderesidencia'];               
  $variable1 = "$ciudad,";
  echo $variable1; //imprime el resultado
  }
```

Hasta aquí todo bien
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el resultado que me da.
Hice dos cosas para que me retornara el resultado en una variable, el problema es que sólo me regresa el último resultado y yo necesito toda la cadena.

Código 1:

```
$objetos= new DB();
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) total_repetidos, Ciudadderesidencia FROM `Solicitudes` WHERE Id_usuarios = 1 && Procesamiento = 1 GROUP By Ciudadderesidencia HAVING total_repetidos > 1 ORDER BY total_repetidos DESC";
$resultado = $objetos->consultaregistros($query);
for($x=0;$x<count($resultado);$x++){          
  $ciudad = $resultado[$x]['Ciudadderesidencia'];               
  $variable1 = "$ciudad,";
  
  }echo $variable1;
```

Me da el último valor del array.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código 2:

```
function revision($resultado){   
    for($x=0;$x<count($resultado);$x++){            
        $ciudad = $resultado[$x]['Ciudadderesidencia'];         
        echo $ciudad; //imprime el resultado
    }
    return $ciudad; 
 }

$objetos= new DB();
$receptividad0 = "SELECT COUNT(*) total_repetidos, Ciudadderesidencia FROM `Solicitudes` WHERE Id_usuarios = 1 && Procesamiento = 1 GROUP By Ciudadderesidencia HAVING total_repetidos > 1 ORDER BY total_repetidos DESC";
$resultado = $objetos->consultaregistros($receptividad0);  
$variable6 = revision($resultado);
  echo "<br>";
  echo "Funcion revision:"; 
  echo "<br>";     
  echo $variable6;
  echo "<br>";
```

Este es el resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hace la consulta bien e imprime el resultado, pero a la hora de retornar me da sólo el último.

Comment: Que es lo que necesitas hacer con la información que devuelve tu consulta?, porque necesitas usar el for()

Comment: Con esa información voy a crear una gráfica, las ciudades son las categorías (labels) y voy a tomar la variable para colocarla en la parte de la función js

Comment: ¿Quieres devolver una cadena con todas las ciudades o un arreglo (array)?

Comment: La cadena con todas las ciudades que genere la consulta

Comment: pe: yo uso Highcharts para la creación de gráficos y para asignar las categorías (en tu caso son los estados) me pide un arreglo(Necesitas guardar en un arreglo tus datos) con las categorías y lo hago de está manera en JS:

res =  json que devuelve tu consulta
let categorias = [];
for(var i in res){
   categorias.push(res[i].Ciudadderesidencia)
}

ya solo cuando creo el grafico asigno el arreglo a la categoria

categories: categorias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas crear una variable antes de iniciar el ciclo e ir actualizando en cada iteración:

```
function revision($resultado){
    // Creas un arreglo para almacenar las ciudades
    $ciudad = [];
    for($x=0;$x<count($resultado);$x++) {
        // Agregas la ciudad al arreglo
        $ciudad[] = $resultado[$x]['Ciudadderesidencia'];
    }
    // Devuelves todas las ciudades ['ciudad1', 'ciudad2', etc.]
    return $ciudad; 
}
```

Si necesitas que sea una cadena cambia el *return* por

```
return implode(', ', $ciudad);
```

Con [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) unes todos los elementos en una cadena y separando con el primer parámetro, en este caso, coma y espacio.

Comment: ¡Gracias! :'DDD

Comment: Si te sirvió, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada, por favor.